# Change properties of an object in an observable array with a Colorpicker

Tags: javascript, razor, knockout.js, observable, color-picker

I have to use data bind on the two colours of a header (one for background, one for text), but I don't want to create two separate observables, just an array with a single object with two properties: MainColor and SecondaryColor initialized with a hex value. (A colorpicker for each property changes the  colours)

I tried this way, but it doesn't work:
(js file)

```
function mainViewModel() {
var self = this;

    self.model = new function () {
        var model = this;
        model.myColor = ko.observable([{
            MainColor: '#0080C0',
            SecondaryColor: '#001111'
        }]);
    }

/* applyBindings is written in another method */

    self.domUtils = new function () {
        var domUtils = this;

        domUtils.initColorPicker = function (selector) {
            $('#' + selector + ' button').colpick({
                colorScheme: 'light',
                layout: 'rgbhex',
                submit: 0,
                color: function () {
                    if (selector == 'MainColor')
                        self.model.myColor()[0].MainColor;
                    else
                        self.model.myColor()[0].SecondaryColor;
                },
                onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb, el) {
                    if (selector == 'MainColor')
                        self.model.myColor()[0].MainColor = '#' + hex;
                    else
                        self.model.myColor()[0].SecondaryColor = '#' + hex;                   
                 },  

                onShow: function (elem) {
                    var top = parseFloat($(elem).css('top').replace('px', ''));
                    var availableHeight = $(window).height();
                    if (top + $(elem).height() > availableHeight) {
                        $(elem).css('top', (availableHeight - $(elem).height() - 20) + 'px');
                    }
                }
            });
        };

        domUtils.initColorPickers = function () {
            domUtils.initColorPicker('MainColor');
            domUtils.initColorPicker('SecondaryColor');
        };
}
```

(cshtml file)

```
<div class="slideshow" data-bind="style: { 'backgroundColor' : model.myColor().MainColor }">
    <div class="slideshow-header slideshow-elements" data-bind="style: { 'backgroundColor' : model.myColor().MainColor, 'color' : model.MyColor().SecondaryColor }"></div>
    <div class="slideshow-button slideshow-elements" data-bind="style: { backgroundColor : model.myColor().MainColor, color : model.myColor().SecondaryColor }">#Next Class</div>                           
</div>
```

I already verified that all this code works using single observable variables like:

```
model.MainColor = ko.observable('#0080C0');
```

But that's not the way I should follow, any thoughts on what may stop the colours from changing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be because `MainColor` and `SecondaryColor` themselves are not observables.Knockout's 'observability' does not trickle down automatically.

Also, since you are using an array, you might be better off using a [observableArray](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html) instead of a simple observable.

Your declaration will then become something like :

```
model.myColor = ko.observableArray([{
            MainColor: ko.observable('#0080C0'),
            SecondaryColor: ko.observable('#001111')
        }]);
```

Note: Rest of your code will have to be changed accordingly in light of this.

Answer (score 0):

The color option only defines the initial value. Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="colpick/css/colpick.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>


    <div class="slideshow" data-bind="style: { 'backgroundColor' : model.myColor.MainColor }">
        <div class="slideshow-header slideshow-elements" data-bind="style: { 'backgroundColor' : model.myColor.MainColor, 'color' : model.myColor.SecondaryColor }"></div>
        <div class="slideshow-button slideshow-elements" data-bind="style: { backgroundColor : model.myColor.MainColor, color : model.myColor.SecondaryColor }">#Next Class</div>

    </div>

    <button id="MainColorButton" data-bind="value: model.myColor.MainColor">Main Color</button>
    <button id="SecondaryColorButton" data-bind="model.myColor.SecondaryColor">Secondary Color</button>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
    <script src="colpick/js/colpick.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        function mainViewModel() {
            var self = this;


            self.model = new function () {
                var model = this;
                model.myColor = ko.observable([{
                    MainColor: '#0080C0',
                    SecondaryColor: '#001111'
                }]);
            }

            self.domUtils = new function () {
                var domUtils = this;

                domUtils.initColorPicker = function (selector) {
                    $('#' + selector + 'Button').colpick({
                        colorScheme: 'light',
                        layout: 'rgbhex',
                        submit: 0,
                        /*
                        color: function () {
                            if (selector == 'MainColor')
                                self.model.myColor()[0].MainColor;
                            else
                                self.model.myColor()[0].SecondaryColor;
                        },
                        */
                        onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb, el) {
                            if (selector == 'MainColor')
                                self.model.myColor()[0].MainColor = '#' + hex;
                            else
                                self.model.myColor()[0].SecondaryColor = '#' + hex; 

                            console.log(self.model.myColor()[0].MainColor);
                            console.log(self.model.myColor()[0].SecondaryColor);

                         },  

                        onShow: function (elem) {
                            var top = parseFloat($(elem).css('top').replace('px', ''));
                            var availableHeight = $(window).height();
                            if (top + $(elem).height() > availableHeight) {
                                $(elem).css('top', (availableHeight - $(elem).height() - 20) + 'px');
                            }
                        }
                    });
                };

                domUtils.initColorPickers = function () {
                    domUtils.initColorPicker('MainColor');
                    domUtils.initColorPicker('SecondaryColor');
                };
            }

            self.domUtils.initColorPickers();
        }

    ko.applyBindings(new mainViewModel());
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```